Rotted Rim Joist/Sill Plate Behind Concrete Patio
hoping for some guidance on a rotted rim joist/sill plate found in the crawlspace. The rim joist in question runs along the front of the house and is parallel to the other joists. I believe the front concrete patio when poured was put in direct contact with the rim joist and over time has resulted in this damage. I have included pictures of the damaged section, which is about 4ft and. Any suggestions as to how I go about fixing this?
Other bits of note, the sill plate is damaged as well. Hard to see but there is a top shot that shows the damage to it. The main support beam running perpendicular to all the joists directly down the middle of the crawlspace is just to the right of this damage. This damage is directly below the front door.
Thank you in advance for your time, really appreciate it.
![Text]()






That's a tough one, and needs to be done by someone who has tackled this type of stuff before.
I believe you are right, the slab was poured tight to the siding at least, and trapped moisture against the house. The brick was added later.
The proper way to make the repair is to  remove the brick sill under the door and remove the brick over the slab. Remove the slab, then the siding which will probably be non-existent, since the rot is evident all the way through the framing. If there is no siding, then good, you have access to the framing. Then the sill and the rim joist can be replaced. With the joists running parallel, there a chance the wall is non-bearing, so there is not that much weight in that 4' span...perhaps.
It can be repaired from the inside, but the water/moisture intrusion that created the problem will still be there. It will not go away by doing the repair from the inside.
Once the framing is repaired the siding or a proper water/weather barrier needs to be installed, with proper drainage so if water gets to the barrier, it has someplace to go. then the brick, then the slab. The brick should be first, since it is part of the weather barrier. The brick takes on moisture, but it protects the barrier from damage. As long as the process of laying the brick, does not damage the barrier. I have seen it happen. Peel and stick membrane is pretty tough, it would be the way to go.

That looks like a precast slab from here. I'd consider getting some help and moving it to see what access that provides. The critical aspect to this repair is to prevent further damage, so start with that in mind. The solution isn't clear, though, as I'm not sure what the water path is from these photos.
Then, you don't necessarily need to remove the damaged board. You could insert a new rim inside and against it. If it's fit well it'll serve to support the wall above just as the original did. Your primary structural concern is preventing sag in that area.
Exactly what I'd replace depends largely on what I could access. You'll have to work through that and see where you land. Good luck.
